# How to get an element in a matrix in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a vector of vectors `[[plate,'p1',0,1],[plate,'p2',0,2],[plate,'p3',1,1]]` containing x,y positions of detected plates.

How do I retrieve the `x` position of plate `p3`?

It seems to be a simple task but I'm more familiar with python, so I'm not sure how to do this in clojure.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 2):

i would go with something like this:

```
(def data [[:plate "p1" 0 1] [:plate "p2" 0 2] [:plate "p3" 1 1]])

(some (fn [[_ v x y]] (when (= v "p3") [x y])) data)
;;=> [1 1]

(some (fn [[_ v x y]] (when (= v "p123") [x y])) data)
;;=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really provide much context on what you're trying to do but it feels like you want to filter the vector of tuples to those that have the symbol `p3'` in the second position and then return just the third and fourth elements of such a match?

If so, the following would work:

```
dev=> (def plate :plate)
#'dev/plate
dev=> (def data [[plate,'p1',0,1],[plate,'p2',0,2],[plate,'p3',1,1]])
#'dev/data
dev=> (let [[[_ _ x y]] (filter (comp #{'p3'} second) data)]
 #_=>   [x y])
[1 1]
```

This doesn't feel very idiomatic, so perhaps you could explain more of the context?

Note: `'p3'` is a symbol whose name is `p3'` so I wonder if you mean `"p3"` for a string?

The vector of vector format doesn't seem very conducive to the sort of access you want to perform - perhaps changing it to a hash map, whose keys are the plate IDs (if that's what `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` are?) would be better to work with?

Edit: in response to @leetwinkski's note about the result when there is no match, here's an alternative:

You could use `when-first`:

```
dev=> (when-first [[_ _ x y] (filter (comp #{'p123'} second) data)]
 #_=>   [x y])
nil
dev=> (when-first [[_ _ x y] (filter (comp #{'p3'} second) data)]
 #_=>   [x y])
[1 1]
```

Comment: Oops, yes I meant "p3". I'm receiving the vector of vectors from an outside source, so I'm trying to work with that where I'm doing exactly what you said: filter the vector of tuples to those that have symbol "p3" in second position and return 3/4th elements.

Comment: This one would act weird if there is no such value in the collection: for `#{"p10"}` it would return `[nil nil]` which is probably not what you want

Comment: True. You could use `when-first` -- I've updated my answer to show that (since code blocks do not format well in comments!).

Answer (score 0):

```
(def p '[[plate,"p1",0,1],[plate,"p2",0,2],[plate,"p3",1,1]])
;; be aware, 'p1' you can use in Python, but because in Clojure `'` at beginning
;; of a symbol is parsed as `quote`, you can't use `''` instead of `""` in contrast to Python.

;; create a nested map out of the vec of vecs
(defn vecs-to-map [vecs]
  (reduce (fn [m [_ id x y]] (assoc m id {:x x :y y}))
          {}
          vecs))
(def m (vecs-to-map p))
;;=> {"p1" {:x 0, :y 1}, "p2" {:x 0, :y 2}, "p3" {:x 1, :y 1}}

;; you can access such a nested list via `get-in` and giving the nested map
;; and the keys it should apply on it.
(get-in m ["p3" :x])
;;=> 1
```

Since the irregularity that one key is a string and the other a keyword is
not so nice, I would make out of them all keywords:

```
(defn vecs-to-map [vecs]
  (reduce (fn [m [_ id x y]] (assoc m (keyword id) {:x x :y y}))
          {}
          vecs))

(def m (vecs-to-map p))

;; access it by:
(get-in m [:p3 :x])
;;=> 1
```

#### Additional Thoughts

We ignored the first element of the vec `plate`.
Let's say there exist also another vectors like

```
(def b '[[box "b1" 0 1] [box "b2" 0 2] [box "b3" 1 1]])
```

And if we want a nested map which contains `:plate` and `:box` in the
outer level as keys, we have to change the `vecs-to-map` function.

```
(defn vecs-to-map [vecs]
  (reduce (fn [m [k id x y]] (assoc m (keyword k)
                                    (assoc (get m (keyword k) {})
                                           (keyword id) {:x x :y y})))
          {}
          vecs))
```

Then we can generate the map containing everything by:

```
(def m (vecs-to-map (concat p b)))

;; or alternatively in two steps:
;; (def m (vecs-to-map p))
;; (def m (merge m (vecs-to-map b)))


m
;; => {:plate {:p1 {:x 0, :y 1}, :p2 {:x 0, :y 2}, :p3 {:x 1, :y 1}}, :box {:b1 {:x 0, :y 1}, :b2 {:x 0, :y 2}, :b3 {:x 1, :y 1}}}
```

And we access the content by:

```
;; access through:
(get-in m [:plate :p3 :x])
;; => 1

(get-in m [:box :b2 :y])
;; => 2
```

Comment: I definitely agree with converting to a map ASAP to work with a more friendly data format. But don't convert strings to keywords just because they look nice. Data from the outside world that may take on any value is usually best represented as a string. Keywords are best when used as source literals.

Comment: i would say that your implementation of `vecs-to-map` is too specific. What i would propose, is to add some general utility like `index-by`: `(defn index-by [kfn data] (into {} (map (juxt kfn identity)) data))` and then `(def indexed (index-by second data))` ; `(some-> indexed (get "p2") (subvec 2))` => `[0 2]`

Comment: @leetwinski True, it is too specific. But I thought it depends a lot on how the row looks like and what one wants to have as key and value ... Perhaps `(defn index-by [kfn vfn data] (info {} (map (juxt kfn vfn)) data))`. And in your case `(def indexed (index-by second #(subvec % 2) data))` - and then: `(get indexed "p2")` => `[0 2]`. And in my case: `(def indexed (index-by #(keyword (second %)) #({:x (third %) :y (fourth %)}) data))`. And then `(get-in indexed [:p2 :x])` => `0`.

Comment: Ah correction for last one: `(def indexed (index-by #(keyword (second %)) (fn [v] {:x (nth v 2) :y (nth v 3)}) data))`

Comment: @leetwinski but programming is sometimes all about being very specific - not everything we have to abstract into highest levels.

Comment: @amalloy Thank you a lot for the hint! I will keep it for the future in my mind! And it totally makes sense!

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would do it, based on [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  Please also note that in Clojure strings always use double-quotes like `"p1"`. Single quotes are totally different!

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn vec-has-label
  "Returns true iff a vector has the indicated label"
  [vec lbl]
  (= lbl (nth vec 1)))

(defn vec->x
  "Given a vector, return the x value"
  [vec]
  (nth vec 2))

(defn find-label
  [matrix label]
  (let [tgt-vecs (filterv #(vec-has-label % label) matrix) ; find all matching vectors
        x-vals   (mapv vec->x tgt-vecs)] ; extract the x values
    x-vals))
```

The unit tests show the code in action

```
(dotest
  (isnt (vec-has-label '[plate "p1" 0 1] "p0"))
  (is   (vec-has-label '[plate "p1" 0 1] "p1"))

  (is= 9 (vec->x '[plate "p1" 9 1]))

  (let [matrix (quote
                 [[plate "p1" 0 1]
                  [plate "p2" 0 2]
                  [plate "p3" 1 1]])]
    (is= (find-label matrix "p3")
      [1])
  ))
```

The unit test show the 2 ways of "quoting" a data structure that contains one or more symbols.  This would be unneeded if the redundant `plate` symbol weren't present.

See also this [list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).